# How to remove the brackets and commas from a .ToString Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a random binary generator.

```
        int onenum = rand1.nextInt(2);
        int twonum = rand2.nextInt(2);
        int threenum = rand3.nextInt(2);
        int fournum = rand4.nextInt(2);
        int fivenum = rand5.nextInt(2);
        int sixnum = rand6.nextInt(2);
        int sevennum = rand7.nextInt(2);
        int eightnum = rand8.nextInt(2);
        int binary[] = {onenum, twonum, threenum, fournum, fivenum, sixnum, sevennum, eightnum};
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(binary));
```

The code needs to be ready to be copied at any time. and a result of 
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1} 
doesn't allow for easy copying.
How do I make the result say 
101101001.

Meaning removing the brackets and commas from the array either before or while its turned into a string.

Comment: Why do you need eight different random number generators?

Comment: Do you care about the number of digits or would any random binary number do? If the latter, try something like `Integer.toBinaryString(rand.nextInt())`.

Comment: This kind of sounds like homework. There is a lot of code smell in the example. Can you give us the specification?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a value you can access later, do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : binary) {
    sb.append(i);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

And if you want an actual binary number out, just parse it using

```
int binaryValue = parseInt(result, 2);
```

Comment: This solution is better, I rushed mine.

Comment: No problem, you can still use System.out.println() if you only want to see it, it just won't help you much if you want to use it later. ;)